# Callback - ReferenceError: Variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I am trying to get some parameters form the URL and pass them on to another function.

The function for getting the parameters is like that:

```
function getUrlVars(callback) {
    var urlVars = {};
    var urlparts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        urlVars[key] = value;

    });
    callback(urlVars);

}
```

It gets the parameters just fine. The function that urlVars should be passed to, looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('done', function() {
    var projSelect = document.getElementById('projectSelection');
    projSelect.value = urlVars[0];
   });
});
};
```

I am calling both functions like so:

```
window.onload=function(){
    getUrlVars(selectBox(urlVars));}
```

So all I am trying to do, is set the value of a selectbox according to a parameter in the URL. But I get an error, telling me that "urlVars" ist not defined.

And quite frankly, I am at my wits end. Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: `var urlVars = {};` is inside the `getUrlVars`. Apparently, you're invoking `getUrlVars(selectBox(` where the `selectBox` argument is `urlVars` which is not defined, I think that's where the script is complaining, since `urlVars` inside the `onLoad` callback is not defined and is not an implicit global.

Comment: That's not what `String.prototype.replace()` is for.

Comment: if selectBox is the function for callback, you do not need to give input, window.onload=function(){getUrlVars(selectBox);}

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having, is that when you are defining the method for `window.onload` you are passing a parameter that is not defined anywhere in your script.

Furthermore, it seems like you want to pass a callback method to `urlVars`, but you are passing a parameter? It is hard to tell by the code that you have provided.

Why not get the parameters you want from your select box and then send them to the desired method?